# How can I make new outline cells be created above the current cell on return?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, cells

When you hit enter inside an item styled cell (e.g. `Cell["", "Outline1"]`), a new cell of the same type is created underneath the cell you are currently editing.

**My question is:** How can I alter this behavior so that when I type the return key the new cell is be created above it instead of below?

**Motivation:** A to-do list. I'd like keep adding items at the top of the notebook section.

Comment: Admittedly not a full answer, but this may help:  NotebookPut[
  Notebook[Reverse[{Cell["number 1"], Cell["number 2"], 
     Cell["number 3"]}]]];

Comment: Let's say you are editing `Cell` which is `"Outline1"` style. Let's say you've typed `"test"` what is expected layout after hiting `Enter`?

Comment: Then a new cell would be created directly above that one and the cursor moves into it...

Comment: And if that cell had a dingbat with a counter it would be incremented on hitting `Enter`

Comment: This is the default behavior of all to-do list apps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a cell below is trivial because we have the built in option `ReturnCreatesNewCell` which can be set to `True` for a given cell style. To add a cell *above* when you hit `Return` you can use `CellEventActions` like this:

```
Cell[StyleData["ToDo", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 CellDingbat->StyleBox["\[FilledSmallSquare]", Alignment -> Baseline, 
   RGBColor[0.8, 0.043, 0.008]],
 CounterIncrements->"ToDo",
 CellEventActions->{
"ReturnKeyDown":>(
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Cell];
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell["New Item", "ToDo"]];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous,Cell];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Before,CellContents])},
MenuSortingValue->3,
StyleMenuListing->True]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! This tweak helps: `Cell[StyleData["ToDo", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 CellDingbat->StyleBox["\[FilledSmallSquare]", Alignment -> Baseline, 
   RGBColor[0.8, 0.043, 0.008]],
 GeneratedCell->True,
 CellAutoOverwrite->True,
 CellEventActions->{"ReturnKeyDown" :> (SelectionMove[
      EvaluationNotebook[], Before, Cell]; NotebookWrite[
      EvaluationNotebook[], 
      Cell["", "ToDo"]];SelectionMove[
      EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, CellContents]; )},
 CellChangeTimes->{3.630533038640272*^9},
 CounterIncrements->"ToDo",
 MenuSortingValue->3,
 StyleMenuListing->True]`

Comment: @M.R. agree. and also `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],Before,CellContents]`

Comment: @M.R. thanks for taking your time and correcting my misinterpretation...